# How to generate permutation of string, but without repeats and different length?

Tags: php, combinations, permutation

I am looking for a php algorithm or just pseudo code to get all permutations of a string, but without repeat of the characters and the length of generated string can variate from 1 to the maximum length of the input. Example:

input: 1 2 3

possible combinations:

1

1 2 / ( it is the same as 2 1, so that must not be calculated)

1 3

1 2 3

2

2 3

3

Comment: And... what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
function pc_array_power_set($array) {
    // initialize by adding the empty set
    $results = array(array());

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));

   return $results;
```

}

[From PHP Cookbook](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_25.htm)